# Kotlin KTOR IPv4 only socket

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, ktor

We're using `ktor-network` for TCP sockets on iOS and Android and on some devices when trying to connect to IPv4 remote address, socket is binded tolocal IPv6 address. For me it looks like `IPV6_V6ONLY` is set, but I see no way nor to check this nor to change.

I can use native C/C++ code to get `AF_INET` socket but would prefer to not use native code. Is there any way to force socket to open on IPv4 address only?

Comment: Can you please try setting the `java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` property on Android?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I've thought about it. But in runtime, it doesn't matter according to documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html 
I'm going to try to put it into `applicationDefaultJvmArgs` but it wouldn't work on iOS anyway.

Comment: I agree about iOS. Ktor doesn't set the `IPV6_V6ONLY` by default. Can you please explain why binding to a local  IPv6 address is a problem?